# Cocoa Bindings: Not key value coding-compliant for the key "hidden2"... what gives?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding

Does anybody know what might be the issue here? I have a couple of NSButton subclasses (although I also tried with vanilla NSButton, same issue) and I'm getting these KVC errors if I try to use the "Hidden2" binding.

```
[<SwiftDefaultApps.SWDACheckbox 0x600000171940> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hidden2.
```

Comment: what is the line of code that crashes. add it to question

Comment: Did you bind anything to `Hidden2`?

Comment: No code. There was indeed a binding on Hidden2, and I think I solved (or at least got around) the issue by inverting the keypaths used in Hidden and Hidden2 (don't ask why that should matter, but it appears to have done the trick)